# Playing Crazyhouse OTB

Tags: chess-variants, otb-chess, crazyhouse

I was playing [Crazyhouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazyhouse) online on [Lichess](https://en.lichess.org/) and I wondered how to play OTB, namely how to change the color of a captured piece.

I came up with 2 methods.

1. Exchange the captured piece for another of a separate chess set, picking the opposite color.
2. Pieces are 2d cards, with the Black version of the piece on one side and White on the other.][3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75NjePOThCk)

Does anyone know better methods?

Comment: Quick dry paint? I think you have already provided the two easiest options. The second one is essentially what happens with Reversi/Othello pieces, which have a white and a black side.

Comment: Usually I find it is best to just play Crazyhouse online... And play Bughouse IRL, which, in my opinion, is way more fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shogi also called "Japanese Chess" use the crazyhouse mechanics as well. They have one-colored  (flat) pieces that always face in one direction. If you capture a piece and bring it back into play you just let it face towards your opponent.

Comment: That's actually another different way than I proposed! Interesting possibility.

Comment: I agree shogi like pieces can be a solution to play OTB ZH.